# Como calcular colunas igual a do Skeleton

Tags: css, grid

A `.col-md-1` é calculado assim: `100/12 = 8.3333...3` no **Skeleton** foi calculado de outra maneira que retornou o seguinte resultado:

```
.one.column,
.one.columns {
  width: 4.66666666667%;
}
```

Qual lógica o desenvolvedor usou? Qual cálculo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente, é um enigma meio complexo de se resolver. Depois de alguns testes e algumas pesquisas, não foi possível obter o resultado de `4.66..67%`, porém cheguei em `4,25%`.

De acordo com [esse problema](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton/issues/72#issuecomment-7433633) no `github`, parece que a base de colunas do `skeleton` antigamente era 16, ao invés do convencional 12 (usado por muitos atualmente - `Bootstrap`).

Outro ponto que analisei, foi o método que muitos estavam calculando a grid do skeleton quando convertido para `SASS` ou `LESS`, ao invés de diminuir o valor de margem para cada lateral (esquerda e direita), foi removido apenas 1 dos lados.

Veja a fórmula usada nesse exemplo de conversão para `LESS`/`SASS`:

```
.one.columns {
    width: @column-width*1-(@column-margin/2)*1%;
}

//Essa área é a interessante para a análise: (@column-margin/2)
```

Considerando que o próprio `github` não é atualizado a 2 anos e que o próprio desenvolvedor falou estar ausente nas atualizações, usando alguns valores do `CSS` original do `Skeleton` e algumas fórmulas usadas em `LESS` e `SASS` cheguei a esse cálculo:

> @larguraTotal = 100;
>   @colunas = 16;
>   @margem = 4%;
>   Fórmula: @larguraTotal / @colunas - (@margem / 2);
>
> ---
>
> 100/16 - (4%/2) = 4,25%

- Link para skeleton SASS, [aqui](https://github.com/whatsnewsaes/Skeleton-Sass).
- Link para skeleton LESS, [aqui](https://github.com/whatsnewsaes/Skeleton-less).

---

Lembrando que a fórmula atual usada em `LESS` e `SASS` já difere do cálculo que eu elaborei, pois hoje o sistema é baseado em uma grid de `12 colunas`, portanto a conta não vai bater. Usei a lógica de cálculo com `16 colunas` (com base na grid usada antigamente) para tentar responder o por que de ser obtido o valor de `4,66..67%` encontrado no arquivo `CSS` original do `Skeleton`.

Comment: Oloco... Eu nunca iria conseguir chegar a 4,25%, obrigado pela sua resposta, vou marca-la como resolvido, já que não se pode obter `4,66...67%`, mas cara será que não é outra lógica ? vou pesquisar mais a fundo, mas acho que não vou obter o resultado diferente, o seu é o mais próximo.

Comment: @GuilhermeSpinXO Como já faz muito tempo que isso foi criado e não é atualizado, talvez foi usado algum guia de "boas práticas" que já não se aplica mais hoje. Por exemplo, o grid do primeiro arquivo publicado (2011) usava `px` ao invés de `%`, talvez tenha sido algum cálculo para fazer essa conversão. Mas sugiro que abandone a tentativa de chegar nesse resultado, já que temos muitos outros frameworks excelentes e atualizados. O que vale a pena é o resultado final =D